# Only arrow functions in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I prefer this:

```
const foo = x => x + 1;
```

to this:

```
function foo(x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

Is there an ESLint rule to enforce this?

Comment: Since they're not freely interchangeable, you probably *shouldn't*.

Comment: It's worth noting that those two are not necessarily equivalent, and enforcing one over the other could cause issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/1650337

Comment: @DBS I am not using features likely to cause issues (such as `this`) either

Answer (score 19):

Anser based on @JohannesEwald comment and @KevinAmiranoff answer.

I'm using the following rules:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style

```
npm install -D eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow
```

`.eslintrc` or `package.json` with `eslintConfig`:

```
"plugins": [
  "prefer-arrow"
],
"rules": {
  "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": [
    "error",
    {
      "disallowPrototype": true,
      "singleReturnOnly": false,
      "classPropertiesAllowed": false
    }
  ],
  "prefer-arrow-callback": [
    "error",
    { "allowNamedFunctions": true }
  ],
  "func-style": [
    "error",
    "expression",
    { "allowArrowFunctions": true }
  ]
}
```

I think this works really well. If you need to disable the rules for a specific line I do it like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line func-style, prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions
```

Comment: Setting "allowArrowFunctions" to true when using func-style of "expression" is redundant.

Comment: Why would you like to enable named function callbacks (by setting `allowNamedFunctions` to `true`) if you generally prefer arrow functions?

Answer (score 15):

You can use this ESLint [prefer-arrow-callback](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) rule which would flag with error/warning anywhere you could use an arrow function instead of a function expression

Comment: But only in callbacks?

Comment: oh yeah true. I guess it is not exactly what you want.

Comment: I use the eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow) in conjunction with `"func-style": ["error", "expression"]` and it works quite well.

Comment: @JohannesEwald I just started using both the plugin and the style rule, and I noticed that I'm getting lot of duplicated errors, that is, lines which are marked as an error by both the plugin and the style rule.

Answer (score 12):

You can use ESLint's built-in [`no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) to disallow the [`FunctionExpression` and `FunctionDeclaration` AST nodes](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/977db0507c4071afa80f92ae10eac1d8/latest):

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      "FunctionExpression",
      "FunctionDeclaration"
    ]
  }
}
```

This doesn't explicitly "prefer" arrow functions, but if you disallow all `ArrowFunctionExpression` alternatives, then you effectively enforce arrow functions only.

With the above rule, these fail:

```js
// VariableDeclaration containing a FunctionExpression
const f1 = function () {}

// FunctionDeclaration
function f2() {}

class C {
  // MethodDefinition containing a FunctionExpression
  m() {}
}
```

These pass:

```js
// VariableDeclaration containing an ArrowFunctionExpression
const f = () => {}

class C {
  // PropertyDefinition containing an ArrowFunctionExpression
  m = () => {}
}
```

If you want to allow `FunctionExpression` and `FunctionDeclaration` nodes when they [reference `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable/34361380#34361380) or when they are generator functions (there's no such thing as an arrow generator function currently), then you can use [`esquery`](https://github.com/estools/esquery) syntax to specifically disallow those nodes when they *don't* have a `ThisExpression` node as a descendant and they *aren't* generator functions:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      "FunctionExpression[generator=false]:not(:has(ThisExpression))",
      "FunctionDeclaration[generator=false]:not(:has(ThisExpression))"
    ]
  }
}
```

With the above rule, these fail:

```js
// VariableDeclaration containing a FunctionExpression
const f1 = function () {}

// FunctionDeclaration
function f2() {}

class C {
  // MethodDefinition containing a FunctionExpression
  m() {}
}
```

These pass:

```js
// VariableDeclaration containing a FunctionExpression containing a ThisExpression
const f1 = function () {
  this.x = 42
}

// VariableDeclaration containing a FunctionExpression[generator=true]
const f2 = function* () {}

// FunctionDeclaration containing a ThisExpression
function f3() {
  this.x = 42
}

// FunctionDeclaration[generator=true]
function* f4() {}

// VariableDeclaration containing an ArrowFunctionExpression
const f5 = () => {}

class C {
  // MethodDefinition containing a FunctionExpression containing a ThisExpression
  m1() {
    this.x = 42
  }

  // MethodDefinition containing a FunctionExpression[generator=true]
  *m2() {}
  
  // PropertyDefinition containing an ArrowFunctionExpression
  m3 = () => {}
}
```

Unfortunately, the function `f` in the following example is also allowed even though it could be rewritten as an arrow function:

```js
function f() {
  function g() {
    this.x = 42
  }

  return g
}
```

I wasn't able to come up with an `esquery` selector that includes functions like `f` while excluding functions like `g`.

Comment: You can an error message too. For example:
`{
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
        {
          "selector": "FunctionExpression",
          "message": "FunctionExpression: Function syntax is illegal. Only arrow functions are allowed"
        },
        {
          "selector": "FunctionDeclaration",
          "message": "FunctionDeclaration: Function syntax is illegal. Only arrow functions are allowed"
        }
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

[allow only arrow function guide](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/function-component-definition.md)

you can refer this.

in the .eslintrc.json file enter these in the rules section:

> "react/function-component-definition": [2, { "namedComponents":
> "arrow-function" }]